# How to show and scale up an element by element of horizontal list of cardviews in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

i want to make a similar horizontal list of items to the one in this picture, please i don' know even how to describe it. When the user swipe an item the complete visible item gets scale up and centered

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Would you show your tries, any code?

Comment: Sorry, i couldn't find a solution to start from

Comment: #Asperi i think this is the solution 
https://medium.com/@superpeteblaze/ios-scaling-carousel-component-in-swift-8f263b1e391